# How to navigate along the function flow and return back to some function in flow during code understanding in NetBeans IDE 7.4

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to understand a big project, I am wondering if there is a simple way to navigate along with the function call and then if required unwind the navigation to return back to some desired function.

Currently I am using bookmark feature in NetBeans, but it's not serving the purpose as it does in one file only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyboard shortcuts to navigate through your code.

There are two shotcuts that could be useful for you :

- **CTRL** + **clik** : Go to the function implementation
- **ALT** + **Left Arrow** : Go back to your previous location (the function call if you used the previous shortcut for example).
- **ALT** + **Right Arrow** : Well, like the previous one, but go forward (useful if you already went backwards)

You can found other navigation tricks in the **navigate** menu. This solution has been tested with Netbeans 8.0.2, but according to this, the shotcuts are the same in your version : https://netbeans.org/project_downloads/usersguide/shortcuts-74.pdf.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

While debugging you can let display NetBeans the callstack via "Window / Debugging / Call stack" (or just press Alt+Shift+3) when you hit a breakpoint.

Or use "Navigate / [Back / Forward]" (shortcuts are Alt + Left and Alt + Right, just make sure your operating system is not handling those shortcuts for something else).